# Why I access more information in Facebook web page than when I using Graph API (for a non-friend user)?

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

When I access a page using a web browser, I can see more information from a non-friend of me user than I can see if I try t get information usin Graph API.

For example:

Accessing the page  http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001514767572 I can see, for example, the location where she is living (São Paulo).

But if I tried to get the information using Graph API, I could not see some information for the same user (https://graph.facebook.com/100001514767572?access_token=XXXX).

PS: I already selected all permission when I got access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook doesn't want it to be too easy for developers to farm certain information.

Comment: But is it possible to access by Graph ? Or we only can do it extracting the information from html files parsing ?

Comment: No you can't access the info by Graph API. Creating a BOT to scrape the pages is your best option.